# Factoring Gaussian integers

Tags: factoring

How do I factor the elements $2, 3$ and $5$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$? Are they not primes, that is $ 2=2 \times 1$, etc? (an exercise from Vinberg's Algebra).

Comment: What is your question exactly ??

Comment: Something is a prime in a ring $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't mean it remains a prime in a bigger ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. In this case, $2$ factors as $(1+i)(1-i) = i^3(1+i)^2$, $5$ factors as $(2+i)(2-i)$ while $3$ remains a prime in the bigger ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Is this what you are asking???

Comment: @achillehui Yes, exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a prime depends very much in what ring we are working. So for instance $2$ and $5$ are primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ while they are composites in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ the Gaussian integers.

One has the following theorem.

> An odd prime number $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is composite in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ if and only $p=4k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. An illuminating theorem, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about both $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ for some small values of $a$ and $b$.